# AndroidX Navigation Drawer

Tags: java, android, android-studio, navigation-drawer, androidx

After searching and searching I can't make the full step to AndroidX. I have problems with Navigation Drawer.

```
<android.support.design.internal.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main_page"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_page_drawer" />
```

I have changed navigationView to bottomNavigationView.

```
    //NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    BottomNavigationView bottomNavView = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    bottomNavView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    View headerView = bottomNavView.getHeaderView(0);
    TextView navUsername = (TextView) headerView.findViewById(R.id.textnav);
    navUsername.setText(str);


public class MainPageActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
```

But I don't get it to work. Now other errors appear,

Error:

> cannot find symbol method
>   setNavigationItemSelectedListener(MainPageActivity)
>                 bottomNavView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
>                                ^ symbol:   method setNavigationItemSelectedListener(MainPageActivity)
>        cannot find symbol method getHeaderView(int) View headerView = bottomNavView.getHeaderView(0);
>                                              ^ symbol:   method getHeaderView(int)

How can I solve all these errors?

Comment: Could you please put the error stacktrace.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

***You should use `headerlayout` for `navigation drawer` instead of BottomNavigation***

`AndroidX` is a major improvement to the original `Android Support Library.`
So to make project use androidX.

- Goto  **`Refactor-> Migrate to androidX.`**
- Add `implementation com.google.android.material.material:1.1.0-alpha09` at `buid.gradle`

In your xml:

```
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_home"
        app:menu="@menu/menu_home_drawer" />

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

In your java file:

```
 navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(YourClass.this);
```

Inside app level theme:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

Comment: cannot find symbol method setNavigationItemSelectedListener(MainPageActivity)

Comment: Glad it helped!!